# Converting case and cast warnings

Tags: c, casting, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to make a program to convert a char to either lowercase or uppercase, depending on what the input is. I don't want to use ctype.h's `toupper()` and `tolower()` functions.

My `ConvertCase` function looks like this:

```
char ConvertCase(char input) {
    char convertedChar = 0;

    if (('a' <= input) && (input <= 'z')) {
        convertedChar = (char)ConvertLowerToUpper;
    }
    else if (('A' <= input) && (input <= 'Z')) {
        convertedChar = (char)ConvertUpperToLower;
    }
    else {
        return input;
    }

    return convertedChar;
}
```

and my two actual converters look like this:

```
char ConvertLowerToUpper(char input) {
    return input - 32;
}
```

with addition instead of subtraction for upper to lower.

When I compile, I get two warnings,

`cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
      convertedChar = (char)ConvertLowerToUpper;`

One for each cast. And I don't really understand what it means. If I omit the casts, I get

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     convertedChar = ConvertUpperToLower;
```

If I ignore the warnings and test my program, it returns a '�' from uppercase to lowercase, a whitespace character from lowercase to uppercase.

How would I fix this? I appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to actually call `ConvertLowerToUpper` and `ConvertUpperToLower`. Right now you're trying to assign the pointers to these functions to `convertedChar`. Hint: when the compiler complains about 'something without a cast', a cast is usually not the solution.

Comment: `ConvertLowerToUpper(input)` instead of `ConvertLowerToUpper`

Comment: Geh. Thank you, @helpYou and Kninnug, I don't know why I didn't realise that! Problem solved! Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: @Dradee No there isn't, which is why people need to stop posting answers in comments!

Comment: No. @Kninnug , can you post it as an answer?

Comment: When the problem & solution is so trivial I just answer in a comment so everyone can move on. But it's in an answer now as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call `ConvertLowerToUpper` and `ConvertUpperToLower`. Right now you're trying to assign the pointers to these functions to `convertedChar`.

Hint: when the compiler complains about 'something without a cast', a cast is usually not the solution.